# Apache / OpenSSL configuration keywords `SSLProtocol` vs. `SSLCipherSuite`

Tags: apache-httpd, configuration, openssl, https

According to the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite) I can configure the cipher suite with (a.o.) two different keywords and examples on Internet often use both (but not necessarily identical to below example).

What is the difference between `SSLProtocol` and `SSLCipherSuite`, should I use them either or both?

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!SSLv2:!SSLv3
```

Or is it better to list individual ciphers for `SSLCipherSuite`?

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA:RC4-SHA ...
```

Are both keywords fundamentally different in what they configure? I have this feeling I am overlooking something essential here.

Above configurations are not necessarily good practice, they're just an example to explain my doubt.

Comment: This was helpful: [Why doesn't the TLS protocol work without the SSLv3 ciphersuites?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70832/why-doesnt-the-tls-protocol-work-without-the-sslv3-ciphersuites)

Answer (score 0):

`SSLProtocol` configures which protocols (SSL or TLS) and which specific versions of those protocols will be allowed.

For example this:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

means enable all supported protocols except SSLv2 and SSLv3.

`SSLCipherSuite` configures which cipher suites can be used. Each of the protocols support different overlapping sets of ciphers; with this you can apply a fine grained setting of exactly which ciphers you want to allow.

In addition to specifying lists of individual ciphers, you can also use aliases such as `SSLv3` (which means all ciphers allowed by the SSLv3 protocol) or `TLSv1` (all ciphers allowed by the TLSv1 protocol).

If you want to control which protocols are supported, then you should use `SSLProtocols`, because it explicitly states that the given protocols will not be allowed, rather than relying on blocking the use of all the ciphers that the protocols allow.